# Autofilter does not filter anything when Criteria is not met

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have a segment of VBA that looks to autofilter out all the rows in which column 37 is blank.  It works great, EXCEPT when there is nothing in the column for the entire data set.  Then, instead of filtering away everything but the header row, autofilter does not filter any rows out.  This results in the adding of the comment "Expected Waste to all the rows instead of just the ones with a value in column 37.  Code is below.  Any help on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

```
'   Filter Data by ExpectedWaste
Sheets("Data").Columns("A:AQ").AutoFilter Field:=37, Criteria1:="<>"


'   Add expected Waste comment
Sheets("Data").Range("AQ2:AQ" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "Expected waste"


'   Unfilter Data
If (Sheets("Data").AutoFilterMode And Sheets("Data").FilterMode) Or 
Sheets("Data").FilterMode Then
    Sheets("Data").ShowAllData
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I test for visible cells before performing any actions.

```
with Sheets("Data").Cells("A1:AQ" & lastRow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=37, Criteria1:="<>"
    with .resize(.rows.count-1, .columns.count).offset(1, 0)
        if cbool(application.subtotal(103, .cells)) then
            'perform actions on .Specialcells(xlcelltypevisible) here
            .columns("AQ").Specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).value = "Expected waste"
        end if
    end with
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `AutoFilter` works with blank columns. Check if there is anything to be filtered first, something along the line of `Cells(Rows.Count, 37).End(xlUp).Row > 1` because otherwise the code you have wrote `Sheets("Data").Range("AQ2:AQ" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "Expected waste"` fills the whole column.

Comment: Thank you.  This is the solution I ended up using with an IF statement to check for > 1 rows and then performing the action.